# Fusion chart Column 2d chart - Inverse axis hide negative sign

Tags: fusioncharts

I'm trying to hide negative(-) sign in Y-axis scale (-200k, -400k...)
Is there any property OR option to hide it. Do the needful.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shankarkl04/mv6hay3a/3/)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Not sure why do you want to remove the negative sign if the values are negative. FusionCharts does have specific charts with Inverse Y axis. There could be an alternative where you have to entirely re-draw your Y axis with their [annotation](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/advanced-chart-configurations/annotations/introduction.html) feature.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes. I'm rendering negative values. I just want to remove negative sign. Annotation feature, let me work on that.